# Can't update multiple state properties at the same time on my React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I do [this project](https://react-projects-1-birthday-reminder.netlify.app/) from [this course](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a_7Z7C_JCyo) and I want to increase the possibilities of the app by giving the user the ability to insert a birthday person by putting the name, age and photo with a HTML form. In order to do so i use this:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
class MyForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      username: '',
      age: null,
      filename: null,
    }
  }
  myChangeHandler = (event) => {
    event.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation()
    let nam = event.target.name
    let val = event.target.value

    console.log('click')
    if (nam === 'age') {
      if (!Number(val)) {
        alert('Your age must be a number')
      }
    }
    this.setState({
      [nam]: val,
      file: URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]),
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="form">
        <form>
          <h1 className="title">
            Today is the Birtday of {this.state.username} of {this.state.age}{' '}
            Years Old
          </h1>
          <img src={this.state.file} alt="Birtday Pic" />
          <p>Enter the name of the Birtday Person:</p>
          <input type="text" name="username" onChange={this.myChangeHandler} />
          <p>Enter his/her age:</p>
          <input type="text" name="age" onChange={this.myChangeHandler} />
          <p>Click on the chosen button to send the birtday pic</p>
          <input
            type="file"
            id="myFile"
            name="filename"
            onChange={this.myChangeHandler}
          ></input>
          <button
            type="button"
            onClick={() => document.getElementById('myFile').click()}
            className="send"
          >
            Send the Birtday Picture
          </button>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default MyForm
```

But here is the issue,I can insert the image but when I tring to put name or age this happends:
[image]
I am just a rookie with React, maybe this is some silly thing, maybe I don't use well setState(), but I can't see the issue right now

Answer (score 1):

You're using the same setState for every change:

```
this.setState({
      [nam]: val,
      file: URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]),
    })
```

HOWEVER, not every event will have `.files` - only the change handler used by the file input.

I would make a separate change handler for the file input. Have one for text inputs, and one for file inputs.

For example, for file inputs:

```
myFileChangeHandler = (event) => {
    event.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation()
    let nam = event.target.name
    let val = event.target.value
   
    this.setState({
      [nam]: val,
      file: URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]),
    })
  }
```

and this for text inputs:

```
  myTextChangeHandler = (event) => {
    event.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation()
    let nam = event.target.name
    let val = event.target.value

    if (nam === 'age') {
      if (!Number(val)) {
        alert('Your age must be a number')
      }
    }

    this.setState({
      [nam]: val,
    })
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @GabrielMC, you solve my problem.